# In c: do internal states improve speed?

Tags: c, performance, function, parameters, state

Lets say I have a function with two parameters that is repetitively called. Does it increase the memory usage when you have functions with arguments?

Would it be faster to generate a function for each repetitive case, and call that function with no parameters?

I believe this is sometimes refereed to as 'internal state', but my question is which of the two options will perform faster?

EDIT>>>>>>>>
Your answers are all enlightening, allow me to clarify all at once.

It seems logical that

```
x = x + 10
```

would be faster than:

```
x = x + y
```

And I'm not talking about the time it takes to define and initialize y, I am just talking about the operation itself. I'm logically, in the second case there must be some extra step in which the CPU must find Y before performing the operation. When you amplify this with functions and then multiply it over and over, I would assume this would make a significant difference.

And yes, what in my case it applies to physics and the speed will likely be felt.

PS I am very interested in compiler functionality and debating learning assembler.

Comment: Whenever you have questions about optimizing for speed, your best bet will always be to profile it. There are a lot of variables that can affect your code's execution time, so profiling is the best way to get a solid answer.

Comment: "generate a function for each repetitive case..." Are you talking specifically about situations when actual arguments are known at compile-time?

Comment: More like they are generated before initiating the main loop, Andrey T.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Is the repetitive call is made with compile-time parameters, then you can indeed improve performance by "instantiating" a special version of the same function for the given set of compile-time parameters. In such cases the function will not even have a "state": the parameter values will essentially be embedded into the function code. Some compilers can do it implicitly.

  The amount of improvement will depend on the nature of the function. In each given version of the function the entire blocks of code might be easily recognized as unreachable and eliminated entirely. One can also say that function inlining by nature involves the same kind of optimization.

  Obviously, using such optimizations thoughtlessly might easily lead to a combinatorial explosion of the number of different versions of the same function (i.e. to code bloat), so it should be used with care.

  (BTW, this is very similar to what C++ function templates with non-type template parameters do.)
- If the repetitive call is made with run-time parameters, then pre-saving them in a run-time state might not achieve any significant improvement. Retrieving parameter values from some "state" is not necessarily more efficient than retrieving them from the "regular" function parameters.

  Of course, there are such classic techniques as packing multiple function parameters into a struct object and passing such struct object to the function (instead of passing a large number of independent parameters). If the parameters remain unchanged between multiple calls, then this does improve overall performance by saving time on parameter preparation. But whether to call such struct object a "state" or not is a different question. It is definitely a manual technique, not something done by the compiler and involving any "internal state".

Comment: This question is a precursor to my pondery about whether 'go to' statements would be faster than functions. Any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 1):

Parameters are typically passed on the stack so they don't take up more memory.
Parameters may be "un-noticeably" slower because the values may be copied to the stack (depends on how good the compiler is at optimizing).

The compiler is way smarter than you are, so don't try to outsmart the compiler. Write clear code and let the compiler worry about performance.

re: your edit

"it depends"

- Does your processor have a different instruction to add 10 to a variable?
- What sort of addressing modes does it support?

Regardless of the answers to the above, does the compiler make use of all the processor's features which might squeeze out every drip of performance.
e.g. - The good old 68000 chips had an "INC" opcode to increment a register by 1. It was much faster than other methods. If you were hand rolling assembly the fastest way to do `x = x + 10` might have been to call INC 10 times...

I've worked with time constrained real time embedded apps and never had to worry about this level of optimization. I'd write the code and worry about performance if/when it becomes an issue.

Answer (score 0):

`Does it increase the memory usage when you have functions with arguments?`
No, function arguments are passed on the stack (or in registers if x64 calling convention).

`Would it be faster to generate a function for each repetitive case, and call that function with no parameters?`
No, your compiler should optimize it for you, there's no need to make your code less readable